# how to upload default file using c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to upload default file (from client/user side) using file upload control. Here file upload control has browse button. My need is: I don't need a browse button just I upload a default file from client side to server which means if every time I click a button, it uploads a specific file for ex: need to upload a file from `D:\iss\backup` without showing file dialog is it possible using `fileupload` control or by using some other methods. Please refer 
my code is:

```
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)    
    {

        filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);

        //string BackupPath;

        ServerPath = @"D:\Iss\Integration\GC1\Backup\" + filename;

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(ServerPath);
    }
```

Comment: you have to set default path or default file for uploading?

Comment: need to set default path

Comment: You can't as far as I know have the browser automatically select a file to upload. The user must always select the file. Otherwise your browser could automatically upload (for instance) `c:\secrets\passwords.txt` or some other file that you *don't* want to upload...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requirement is to copy file from one path (folder) to another. Below is the code which performs the same without Browse button.

```
string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(destinationFileName);
// If directory doesn't exist create one
if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
{
  DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
}
File.Copy(sourceFileName, destinationFileName);
```

Above code you can implement on button click or on page load depending on your requirement.